# How does redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" actually work?

Tags: asp.net, iis, error-handling, web-config, custom-errors

**EDIT**
So I managed to *fix* it by defining an `Application_Error` method in my `Global.asax` and call `Response.ClearContent` from there. Not sure if this could have any undesirable side-effects though, so still interested in answers to the original question. **/EDIT**

I have set up the `<customErrors>` element in my Web.config using `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"`. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.customerrorsredirectmode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_CustomErrorsRedirectMode_ResponseRewrite) this should *display the error page without changing the original URL.*

This works fine if an exception is thrown in one of the page events like `Page_Load`, however I noticed when you throw an exception from an inline code-block in your .aspx file, it will output whatever you had in your .aspx file up to the line where the exception is raised and then append the contents of your error page to that, resulting in total garbage on the client's end.

Take this simple page, with a `Web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and `error.aspx` page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   An error occured
 </body>
</html>
```

and a `default.aspx` that raises an exception

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<% string s = null; %>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <strong>This is a test page.</strong>
  <%= s[0] %>
 </body>
</html>
```

Requesting `default.aspx` in the client's browser will result in the following garbled HTML being served

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <strong>This is a test page.</strong>
  
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   An error occured
 </body>
</html>
```

Does this happen because at this stage the HTML of default.aspx file has already been written to the output stream? If so, is there anyway to clear the contents of the output stream so that only the contents of the actual `error.aspx` will be send to the client? I tried calling `Response.ClearContent()` in the Page_Load of my error page, but that had no effect.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening other than resorting to `redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"`? Also, if what I wrote above is true, how come `redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"` works in this situation? If the output stream has already been written, HTTP headers must already have been sent, right?

Comment: You can not do anything - this kind of error that you throw in the middle of the render (and not on code behind) and all ready you have send some page, is first of all rare - so why to bother to make something more complicate to handle the error and not fix the error ? Part of the page is all ready render, only if you use `ResponseRedirect` you can avoid this type of render, or if you use try/catch and handle your error.

Comment: This is caused by <%= ... %>. <%= ... %> is equivalent to Response.Write(...), if an exception occurs in <%= ... %>, error.aspx will be written directly by Response.Write(...) and the content in default.aspx will not be cleared.

Comment: Embedded code blocks are supported in ASP.NET Web Forms pages primarily to preserve backward compatibility with older ASP technology. In general, using embedded code blocks for complex programming logic is not a best practice, because when the code is mixed on the page with markup, it can be difficult to debug and maintain. So I do not recommend that you use <%= ... %> in Web Forms.